# ¿Cómo hacer un loop con timeout?

Tags: r, curl

Tengo un código en R que chequea si un ***set*** dado de direcciones URLs existen o no. Para lo cual cuento con un vector que contiene las urls llamado *"pagina"* y utilizo la función `url.exists` del paquete `RCurl` para ir chequeando la existencia de cada una en un bucle ***for***.

```
require(RCurl)
for (i in 1:dim(pagina)[1]) {
urllogic[i]<- url.exists(urli, useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36")
}
```

Sin embargo en algunas urls especificas, se queda congelado y no continúa ejecutando el código.
¿Cómo puedo modificar el código para que pase de largo aquellos registros que tarden más de (por ej.) 30seg en chequearlos?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Quedan congeladas, o dan un error? Si dan un error puedes incorporar un `tryCatch` como en los [ejemplos aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093914/skip-to-next-value-of-loop-upon-error-in-r-trycatch).

Comment: @FvD no da error, simplemente queda congelada porque según lo que averigüé , la página al no reconocer el useragent mata la IP y el script se  queda intentando ingresar pero nunca obtiene respuesta

Comment: Una duda, ¿para qué necesitas definir el `useragent` en este caso concreto?

Comment: Porque hay URLs que si no lo tengo definido, mata la IP y no me devuelve error.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te puede funcionar es hacer una combinación de `tryCatch()` con `evalWithTimeout()` como escrito por [Bengtsson en R.utils](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/263047.html). Por ejemplo algo como:

```
require(RCurl)
for (i in 1:dim(pagina)[1]) {
   tryCatch({
     evalWithTimeout({
        urllogic[i] <- url.exists(urli, useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36")
     }, timeout=2.0)
   }, TimeoutException=function(ex) {
        cat("Timeout. Pasando de largo.\n")
      }
   )
}
```

Escribi el codigo sin probarlo, asi que seguramente tiene un error, pero este es el camino por donde puedes llegar a la solución que buscas. La documentación es parte de R.utils [evalWithTimetout](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/r.utils/docs/evalWithTimeout).